# Disable xscreensaver when program is running?

Tags: screensaver, screen-lock

I find it very annoying that xscreensaver sometimes helpfully starts while I'm playing Urban Terror, and was wondering if there is a better way to solve this than making some script to run Urban Terror which kills xscreensaver first.
My system is Arch Linux, with xscreensaver 5.22.

Comment: What desktop environment or WM are you using?

Comment: @terdon Mostly cinnamon, some gnome3, some xfce, and sometimes wmii or kde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use caffeine

```
yaourt -S caffeine-bzr
```

if yaourt installed

otherwise you will have to build it from here

[AUR For caffeine-bzr](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/caffeine-bzr/)

after it is running.  Activate it.

It differs slightly based on DM how to set it up.  You just need to add the executable to caffeine.

I am not familiar with Urban Terror, but you might have to include the wine part of the executable when configuring caffeine

Comment: Urban Terror is Linux -- it's in the Arch Repositories.

Comment: Once again, caffeine helps for everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The latest versions of Cinnamon come with their wn screensaver package so these solutions might not work, but they do on my Cinnamon 1.8.8.

### lightsOn

LighstOn is a simple BASH script that will inhibit the screensaver when it detects any of a list of user defined programs (mplayer, and therefore smplayer, are on the list by default) running **in full screen mode**.

Download lightsOn from [here](https://github.com/iye/lightsOn/blob/master/lightsOn.sh). I just tried it and it works perfectly. You might want to make it start automatically by adding it to Cinnamon's start up application list.

### caffeine

Caffeine is a system tray applet for Gnome3 (it may or may not work in Cinnamon, I have not tried it). According to [this site](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/2-ways-to-temporarily-disable.html), you can give it a list of programs and it will inhibit the screensaver if they are running (full screen or not). According to the same site, it can work with both `xscreensaver` and `gnome-screensaver` so you may want to check it out.

Comment: I'm now using caffeine, on DarkSheep's advice. It works in cinnamon.